# Best way to get object movement between frames?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, opticalflow

so I'm currently detecting and localizing an object between two subsequent frames, and due to the nature of the localization algorithm I'm employing, the bounding box may vary in size between different frames, even though it's detecting the same object (albeit not by much). I need to calculate how much a certain object has moved between the two frames.

Originally I was planning on using something light like Lucas-Kanade Opticalflow and calculating the median distance of points between the two frames. While relatively simple, I was wondering if there are any better feature-based‌ alternatives for calculating how much an object has moved between two subsequent frames?

Many thanks.

Comment: strongly depends on the quality of images, the nature of the object, the kind of distortions during motiob (do you see the same parts of the object or are there perspective effects? Does the object rotate?) etc.. Keypoint matching is good for high resolution textured objects. Chamfer matching with a tracker like particle filtering or kalman is good for objects with edges, etc...

Comment: @Micka The object may change a bit due to lighting and such, that's why I'm going for a more feature-based tracking algorithm. As I understand it, in practice, Kalman is only good when the object is continuously moving, and you also need to know how much it's moved/at what speed. Did you mean Sobel edge detection by any chance?

Comment: sobel canny lsd. The important part is the quality of the edges and the similarity measures afterwards + the tracking methods afterwards. If you want a simple and good solution which works in many applications, try SIFT/SURF/ORB in the way you've used optical flow so far. The edge based methods will need sophisticated algorithm work specialized for your task. You can have a look at opencv tracking api, which provides some general purpose tracker methods, but I found them not to be good/stable enough for my applications yet.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for the advice! Can you please write it up as an answer so I can accept/vote it?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: the object does not change much over frames, and it takes up a reasonable amount of pixels in a bounding box

Constraint: Low-latency lightweight solution

Solution: Lucas Kanade Tracking

Do not confuse this with Lucas Kanade optical flow. Look at figure 2 in this [paper](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/baker_simon_2004_1/baker_simon_2004_1.pdf)("Lucas-Kanade20YearsOn:A UnifyingFramework")

Note that in this approach you have the freedom to define your between frames transform. If, for example, you know that there will be no camera/object rotation, then you should set that to zero in the optimization procedure for better results. If full Affine is what you need, then go for that by all means